# getComputedStyle of a node in chrome is empty

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have the following line in my javascript code :

```
if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){
    strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oElm).getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
} // ...
```

To retrieve a CSS value of my node (eg: `strCssRule = 'color'`). It works on Firefox. It works on Chrome only on simple examples on a static page. When trying to integrate it in complex my application, every fields of the returned `CSSStyleDeclaration` are null.

The node `oElem` is retrieved using jQuery (`oElem = $(my_selector).empty().get(0));`). The difference (at least the only one I could think of) between working example and my application is that my node is not integrated yet in the DOM at the time to computation (still generating the full HTML).

I tried even when setting explicitly the CSS in the HTML delectation (eg my node is `<div style="width:100px;"></div>`), the CSSStyleDeclaration object is still empty.

**Edit**: as mentioned CBroe, the problem is that the element is not linked to the DOM yet. I guess it depends of the implementation of the browser how this case is handled. I don't know how firefox was able to  make it works but I will find something else.

Comment: _“that my node is not integrated yet in the DOM”_ – of course this is the reason. An element not in the DOM is not worth the expensive task of rendering it already – so there are not computedStyles to read for such an element. Put it into the DOM first – hidden, if necessary (not using display:none though, because that has basically the same effect as the node not being in the DOM).

Comment: But why does it work in firefox then ? Unfortunately I can not integrate it at that point without changing a lot in the rendering process of my application.

Comment: It works in Firefox since [it's the only browser that actually bothered to implement this for detached nodes](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9338).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the selector of the CSS rule, and you know that it is defined in the CSS sheets, you can search for it. That is how I rounded this problem.

```
var page, rule, css;
var selector = ".my_selector";
var sheets = document.styleSheets;
for( page = 0; page < sheets.length; page++ ){
    // if you comment out this if-statement, you can search thru all of the page-wide stylesheets
    if( sheets[page].href.match(/.*\/filename\.css$/) ){
        for( rule = 0; rule < sheets[page].length; rule++ ){
            if( sheets[page][rule].selectorText === selector ){
                css = sheets[page][rule].style;
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}

// At this point, you have access to the CSS you're looking for.

console.log(css);
alert(css.backgroundColor);

// example from actual code:

if(css.borderTopWidth)this.speaker_default.edge._sizediff=Number(css.borderTopWidth.slice(0,-2));
```